# ASP.Net handler request stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack, client-server, handler

I've got a slightly odd requirement that I'm not sure how to properly articulate.

I essentially want to prioritise the *most recent* requests to an ASP.Net handler. I'm not sure if this should be client-side or server-side. I'm leaning towards server side to ensure it's enforced on all clients.

So, as requests come in, they're essentially stacked according to some internally-defined time interval, per client. Then, the top of the stack (most recent) request is processed first.

The reason for this is that the clients will be requesting resources as a user interacts with a client. But the user only cares about the most recent request that's made (think constantly seeking in a streamed file - I want to serve the most recent requests first, since that's where the user will want the media to begin playing).

How should I approach this? I was thinking something like a singleton, that all requests were sent to, and it handled stacking requests from each client, then sent them off to be processed.

I'm after some suggestions for other ways to implement what I'm suggestion (don't have to use a stack). Or pros/cons and pointers for what I've described here.

**Update**: This may be possible, but it is very difficult to get reliable. I can get the requests to be processed out of order, but they are sometimes missed or not received by the client. I'm starting to think that perhaps this is client-side functionality, rather than server-side. The client should manage requests more carefully.

Eg. implement a monitor/timer that only sends requests when it determines that the user will likely need the resource. This could be after seeking or if the position is change slowly rather than quickly.

Comment: Is it an option to cancel the request in javascript on the client? in AJAX you should have this option, but I don't know whether this would actually cause the request to be cancelled at the server too.

Comment: Surely the browser will only accept a response to its most recent request. If I'm reading correctly you want the server to respond out of order than to the requests that were made?

Comment: I think what he really wants is to drop requests from the queue if a more recent request is available. Correct?

Comment: @Pieter this is not using javascript.

Comment: @eddy556 @Pieter I still want all requests to be responded to, but not in the order the arrived. I don't want the requests dropped, they still need to return eventually.

Comment: @cofiem - I'd love to see if this is possible

Comment: @eddy556 yes, I'm not entirely sure if it is possible. So far, I am able to respond in a different order, but it is very hard to separate out _per client_.

Comment: Perhaps a bounty will help, I'd also be very interested.

Comment: It seems like there should be a way to do this, but it is very complicated, and there is not a huge gain. Seems like the idea is more to leave the requests alone, and concentrate on making whatever processing is done concurrent or smarter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting theoretical problem so here's how you might do it in very broad strokes:

1. Create a singleton class containing a LIFO stack collection
2. At the beginning of the request pipeline, add a reference to the request thread to the queue.
3. Have the request thread peek the stack collection until the current thread is the next on the queue
4. Pop the thread reference from the Stack and complete the remaining request pipeline.

You'll probably run into some kind of catastrophe with the limited thread pool or race conditions or global thermonuclear war sooner or later, but you should expect that, seeing  as you're trying something experimental to begin with.

Comment: I'll give you the answer for this one, since you're the only response, and you did respond to my request for input. I do not recommend not trying this, it should probably be addressed by dropping requests as @Pieter said, or making the requests queued or combined.